# TFS Api - Erro em query com DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, team-foundation-server

Estou tentando realizar uma consulta utilizando a API do TFS onde preciso obter todos os WorkItens que foram editados a partir de uma determinada data, no entanto recebo o seguinte erro:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ValidationException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll
>
> Additional information: You cannot supply a time with the date when
>   running a query using date precision. The error is caused by «[Changed
>   Date] > '09/11/2015 14:12:43'».

Eu preciso consultar utilizando a data e a hora, mas acho que é isso que está causando o erro, abaixo o código que estou utilizando para a consulta:

```
var query = "SELECT [ID] FROM WorkItem WHERE [Work Item Type] = '{0}' AND [Changed Date] > '{1}'";
var workItens = GetWorkItemStory().Query(string.Format(query, WORKITEM_TYPE, dataBase));
return (from WorkItem workItem in workItens select workItem).ToList();
```

Alguma ideia do que eu possa fazer para resolver o problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi utilizando uma "POG" com linq.

Ao obter os itens da Api busco todos com a data igual ou maior do que eu quero, sem considerar a hora, em seguida, faço um linq para buscar somente a partir do horário que desejo. Não é algo bonito mas é funcional.

```
var query = "SELECT [ID] FROM WorkItem WHERE [Work Item Type] = '{0}' AND [Changed Date] >= '{1}'";
var workItens = GetWorkItemStory().Query(string.Format(query, WORKITEM_TYPE, dataBase.ToShortDateString()));
return (from WorkItem workItem in workItens where workItem.ChangedDate > dataBase select workItem).ToList();
```

Mas se alguém souber me explicar o motivo e uma solução mais "bonita" vou aceitar como resposta.

Comment: Não é POG. É o jeito certo mesmo. +1.

Comment: @pedrocamarajunior o linq ajuda muito, deixa o código mais enxuto!